# Use different filtering criteria with tcpdump packet size

Tags: tcpdump

When running `tcpdump` like this

```
tcpdump -s96 -i eth0 ip -w output_filename
```

is it possible to tell `tcpdump` to get the entire packet when a packet is a DNS request/response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

The underlying BPF engine could do it on *some* platforms, but the filter language that compiles to BPF code doesn't support that (and it would take either a change to the filter language, or a change to the tcpdump command-line syntax to support multiple filters and -s flags, to support that, as well as significant changes to the BPF compiler, so that's not likely to happen soon).